# If/And functions are not working correctly in my formula, can someone help me?

Tags: excel, formula

I have a field in my excel spreadsheet that depends on several different fields to determine the calculation that should be made.  I think I have my formula correct but I am not getting the appropriate responses so I know there must be something I am missing.  Let me start by summarizing what I am attempting to do.

If `D5=2`, then I need to verify if `$AI$12-AB14>(3/24)` and return a `T` if it is or leave the field blank if not.  Alternatively, if `D5=1`, then I have to also verify that `Y14=Y` and `Z14=Y`, and finally `$AC$12-AA14>(3/24)` and return a `T` if so, or leave the field blank if not.

(The reference to 3/24 is required as I am performing time calculations from data entry fields pulling from a userform)

What I am receiving for a response is 'True'.  That is not an option so I suspect it is returning the result of a specific logical statement?  Below is my formula:

```
=IF(AND(D5="2",$AI$12-AB14>(3/24),),"T","") 

=IF(AND(D5="1",Y14="Y",Z14="Y",$AC$12-AA14>(3/24),),"T","")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. *Can someone help me* is not an acceptable question here, and Excel formula is indicated by the tags and isn't needed in the title. Your title should describe a problem or ask a question that contains enough information to be of use to a future reader here who is scanning through a list of search results trying to find an answer, and your current title does not provide that information. Thanks.

Comment: You have comma after ...>(3/24) expression, why? This always returns a false for AND part.

Comment: I changed that but I am still not getting a correct response.  :(  Please note, both lines are one formula.  I was directed to edit my post and it separated these into separate lines...  it almost looks like they are different formulas.  :)

Comment: Oh, that's one formula. And what are you waiting for? You compare two if expressions where both have the same false result, which in turn gives a true result. I.e. if(...,"T","")=if(...,"T","") => ""="" => True

Comment: I want excel to determine, based on D5, which calculation to use?  I've been working in VBA a lot and now that I'm out of VBA, I'm struggling trying to get Excel formulas to make sense to me again.  D5 determines if this is an employee or volunteer and there are different rules for each.

Comment: well then maybe try this:
IF((D5="2")*($AI$12-AB14>(3/24)) + (D5="1")*(Y14="Y")*(Z14="Y")*($AC$12-AA14>(3/24)),"T","")

Comment: I think my description must have confused the matter.  I need 2 different calculations, based on what D5 value is.  If it is 2, then I need to verify if AI12-AB14>(3/24) and if so, return T, if not, return nothing.  If however, D5 value is 1, then I have to verify if Y14 is Y, and if Z14 is Y, and then if AC12-AA14>(3/24) and return T if if so, and nothing if not.  Is this not possible?  So there are 2 different if statements based on what the value in D5 is.

Comment: My formula does just that. Have you tried it? Didn't work?

Comment: No, it did't work.  :(  Wonder what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can't insert an image in comments, so I'll reply. This simplified example shows how it works:
[image]

And pay attention to D5 - are there really values 1 and 2 as text. If not, the quotation marks must be removed from the formula